# EmberJS filter hasMany data, apply to belongsTo relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I have this teams model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    "name": attr('string'),
    "players": DS.hasMany('player',{
        async: true
    })
});
```

along with this player model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    "name":  attr('string'),
    "status": attr('string'),
    "team": DS.belongsTo('team',{
        async: true
    })
});
```

If I want to list out all the teams, easy enough.  And if I want to list out all the teams, and within each team, list out all the players... also simple enough.

```
{{#each teams as |team index|}}
    <strong>{{team.name}}</strong></br>
    <em>Players</em>
    <ul>
    {{#each team.players as |player|}}
        <li>{{player.name}} - {{player.status}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

My QUESTION... let us say certain players are injured.  If I'm looping through the teams, how would I go about ONLY displaying Teams that have injured players. If at least one player is injured, the TEAM will display, if not... the team will not display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5ef83018c9fdef3e57be5b12c7e3cd5e)

Comment: with pulling data from a database, I'm having an issue getting it to render.  In other words, if I load the record with all the relationships, I either needs to save the record (for it to show the filtered results) or in a beforeModal, load in the other has many records.  Is there a way I can call the computed property later? or some other means?  PS, thank you for the twiddle... very helpful!

Comment: @Matt I don't understand what is the issue! If you want to filter the team based on player (relationship) so you load relationship implicitly in the way ember data defined. Please get more info about the issue you mentioned

Comment: What I'm saying is, it seems as though the filter runs before the all the models load, since all of the model data is not there, it does not display the content.  Is there a way to delay when the computed property runs, or tell it to 'wait' for all of the models to load first?

Comment: @Matt You're wrong. The computed property runs whenever `model` would be presented. I updated the twiddle to show this

Comment: Ok there must be something else at play then, thank you for the help.

Comment: @Matt You're welcome. If there is issue more existed, feel free to ask

Answer (score 2):

You can try filtering using `isAny` method for `players`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('team').then((teams)=>{
            return teams.get('players').then((players) => {
                return players.isAny('status','injured');
            })
        })
    }
})
```